# exceptions when refreshing the account: InvalidConversationCredentialsExceptionFaultMessage and StaleConversationCredentialsExceptionFaultMessage

Tags: yodlee

When I tried to add some accounts to yodlee, the program took a long time to refresh the accounts. After refreshing for more than 3 mins, the program threw the exception "InvalidConversationCredentialsExceptionFaultMessage" or "StaleConversationCredentialsExceptionFaultMessage".

I have several accounts with this problem. All the other accounts work fine.

Could somebody tell me why these kinds of exceptions happen and how to solve them?

Thanks a lot.
MCC

Answer (score 1):

You get "InvalidConversationCredentialsExceptionFaultMessage" when the user context gets expired. This can be corrected by re initiating the user context

With respect to "StaleConversationCredentialsExceptionFaultMessage", you get this when yout ry logging in the same user multiple times (create user contexts)and try to use the user context that is already invalid by the subsequent one.

Please let me know if you need more information.

--Vijay

Comment: Hi Vijay: Thanks a lot for your response. It helps a lot. Could you please tell me how long it will take for user context expires? Because sometime it works fine but sometime it threw that exception.

Comment: The user context expires after 15 minutes.

Comment: it will expire after 15 mins if there is no activity? or it will expire anyway? What if one user have 50 accounts and it need more than 15 mins to refresh all the 50 accounts?